# An interesting puzzle for some, confusing for me

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, puzzle, order-theory

Suppose that $a$ is of odd order $k$ and $bab=a$. I need to show that $b$, must be of order $2$.  We can prove this anyway we want to, but our hint is to expand $(bab)^k$ and re-associate and then prove that $ab^2=(b^{-1})^2a$ "to collapse the expression in pairs."

Alright since, $a$ is of odd order $k$, $k=2n+1$ for $n\in Z.$  So if we multiply $a$ by itself $k$ times we get $a^k=e$. And we know $bab=a$. What would be the next step here? Would I have to say that $(bab)^k=a^k=e$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$bab^{-1}=b^2a$$

So 
$$e=(bab^{-1})^k=(b^2a)^k=(b^2a)^{k-2}b^2ab^2a
=(b^2a)^{k-2}a^2=\cdots =b^2a^k=b^2$$

Comment: how does $bab^-1=b^2a$? I dont see how the hint proved helps, thats my thing

Comment: @Jack: Multiply both sides of $bab=a$ by $b$ on the left and $b^{-1}$ on the right.